# How to store data in a database for multiple purposes

Tags: database, web

I am trying to get some ideas for storing text in a database. This data will be used on a web page but also will be used to share with other users outside of the web page. There are instances that I would like to use italicization or bold text, break into paragraphs, etc for the web page. I am also going to be allowing others to access the db to pull this information into their own application may be a web page, another database, vb application, etc. What would be the best way to do this and not have a format that may not be supported by the clients program? I read some post where they suggested to store the data as XML and then I could strip it out if I didn't need it. I am not that advanced so seems it may be difficult. I welcome all suggestions....

Comment: Interesting point that the rawest form may be that the formatting is part of my data, I think that in some instances it is. The issue I am running into is how do I format the data so that it is usable to the widest range of applications. For my web site using HTML in the database will work for me however I will also be selling the data to subscribers who needs to use it in their own application that is not html or web based. I want to be able to highlight, bullet, italicise certain important points. Is there a universal way to do this so it can be shared amongst everyone?

Answer (score 2):

Avoid storing rendering data in your database - store just the data in its rawest form. Let the user of the data decide how to format it. Perhaps, if formatting is *part* of the data (ie you're storing "documents") you could store as markup/markdown (good point from @pst).

Another way of looking at it is to store the data *without assuming what it's used for*. That way, it's easiest to maintain and use for your initial uses, and more in the future.

Comment: Markdown/markup formats (vs. "rendered" XML/HTML) might be appropriate to talk about .. there is no reason why the XML *couldn't* function as the syntax for a neutral format (and in extension limited HTML could be viewed as as such a neutral format, preferably handled abstractly). That is, the data *might* include formatting and this *might* be the "rawest form".

Comment: @pst personally I detest XML. The name for an XML file is "document" - that alone should send you running for the hills. It's not a good data format IMHO. Perhaps markdown, but KISS applies

Comment: The format usually doesn't matter to me .. as long as I have a library to deal with it. XML, while not generally being human-friendly (compared to alternatives like JSON or YAML or..), is a very consistent format that can handle a wide variety of data-representaiton and works well with countless existing tooling .. including databases.